# JQuery Mobile Listview search types

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with searching in JQuery Mobile listview control.

In listview default search like this:
Listview Items:
AAA
BBB
CCC
ABB
BAB
CBA

When I search "A" I will get the Result
Current Displaying Items:
AAA
ABB
BAB
CBA

But I want the Items:
AAA
ABB

Answer (score 0):

Add a [custom filter callback](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/02/14/jquery-mobile-tip-write-your-own-list-view-filter-function/).

Try something like this (untested):

```
var filter = function( text, searchString ) {
    return text.toLowerCase().indexOf( searchString ) !== 0;
};

$('#myListView').listview( 'option', 'filterCallback', filter );
```

I wrote this on my phone so that's my excuse for everything wrong with this answer.